# tee pipeline and pnmtools - truncated file

Tags: command-line, pipe, tee, truncate, netpbm

This sequence of commands works OK:

```
pngtopnm file.png 2> /dev/null > dump1
pnmfile < dump1
stdin:  PPM raw, 1920 by 1080  maxval 255
ls -l dump1
-rw-r----- 1 cmb 6220817 Sep 15 14:26 dump1
```

But redoing the pipeline to use 'tee' **truncates the output** in the dump file:

```
pngtopnm file.png 2> /dev/null | tee dump2 | pnmfile
stdin:  PPM raw, 1920 by 1080  maxval 255
ls -l dump2
-rw-r----- 1 cmb   49152 Sep 15 14:34 dump2
```

I'm not clear on what difference it makes where 'tee' is sending stdin to what gets saved in the dump file - why is 'dump2' truncated, and not identical to 'dump1'?

```
cmp dump[12]
cmp: EOF on dump2 after byte 49152, in line 4
```

I suspect its something to do with 'pnmfile', since putting something else at the end of the pipeline seems to work OK - 'dump3' is the right size/same content as dump1, and the end of the pipe ('fmt') is doing something to the file...:

```
pngtopnm file.png 2> /dev/null  | tee dump3 |fmt -10 > dump4
ls -l dump[34]
-rw-r----- 1 cmb 6220817 Sep 15 14:41 dump3
-rw-r----- 1 cmb 6224311 Sep 15 14:41 dump4
```

(XUbuntu 20.04, diffutils 3.7, Netpbm 10.0, coreutils 8.30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pngtopnm file.png 2> /dev/null | tee dump2 | pnmfile
```

`pnmfile` only reads until it has enough information to output the file information and then closes the pipe. At that point tee closes the pipe and dump2 as well.

Try `tee -p dump2`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Man page entry for the -p option to tee wasn't particularly clear...